# TF-IDF vs XGBoost vs CNN

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf-idf

I have a Natural Language Dataset where I am performing classification.

The tf-idf model always performs better than a Convolutional Neural Network model.

I have performed a lot of hyperparameter tuning but the performance of the tf-idf model remains better.

In fact, the tf-idf model is performing better than a XGBoost model as well.

Can we safely say that in certain scenarios basic and primitive Machine Learning Models can perform better than Deep Learning models?

Comment: what is your data size? number of classes?

Comment: @vumaasha My data contains around 85000+ documents and 16 classes.

Comment: could you also give some idea as to how much the performance differs? Showing some code might be helpful as well. It could also be due to a bug in preprocessing for e.g

Comment: **Accuracies** : Tf-Idf based Logistic Regression: 70.59%, XGBoost: 68.22%, CNN: 65.88%

The accuracies are obtained on a common Validation Set.

Comment: i am suspecting that this could be a bug in the way you generate TF-IDF vectors. Are you using sklearn? are you building the TF-IDF on the whole dataset in a single shot

Comment: I am using sklearn

Comment: You need to fit the tf-idf vectorizer only on the training set and use it to transform the validation set. That way your TF-IDF values wont be biased by the validation vocabulary.

Comment: I am doing that itself. My point is even if I assume that Tf-Idf might have a problem, the CNN model should ideally be performing better.

Comment: it's very hard for anyone to help unless you give more details of what hyper parameters, architecture, you are using. The reason for asking about TF-IDF is may be you are seeing better results due to a bug. On a sidenote, Since this is a text classification setup, i could suggest you to give it a try using fasttext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my findings, I worked on a Question Classifier using high dimensional features based on Named Entity Recognition, Lemmatization and POS tags. Since each document now has a high dimensional vector, algorithms such as SVM perform better than RNNs. Hence, I can safely conclude that the traditional ML algorithms can perform better then Deep Learning based models for certain datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You should test a RNN model. I don't think your primitive Machine Learning Models are better than a RNN model.